# How to organise, test, document and package a Clojure project

Tags: clojure, projects-and-solutions

I've been learning some Clojure, and I currently have a single `.clj` file which I edit in a text editor and which I execute on the command line.

Where can I find a guide on the practical aspects of scaling this up to larger programs/libraries?

- How should I lay out multiple `.clj` files on the filesystem?
- How should I organize and execute test code?
- How should I document the program/library?
- How should I package it?

I'm looking for information on the practical aspects on scaling up from small scripts to something real.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend using [leiningen](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen). Running

```
$ lein new myproject
```

will create a new folder called `myproject` inside your current working directory with a default skeleton structure.

Inside the newly generated`myproject` folder you'll find (among others) a folder named `src` for clojure source code and a folder named `test` for your tests (leiningen will generate a default failing test).

Leiningen will let you run your tests with `lein test`.

You can package your project as a jar file with `lein jar` or create an uberjar (an executable jar with all required dependencies included) with `lein uberjar`.

For generating documentation I recommend [autodoc](http://tomfaulhaber.github.com/autodoc) which integrates nicely with leiningen.

Comment: Leiningen looks perfect, it contains a nice tutorial on how it works:
http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Netbeans, there is a Clojure plugin which could be helpful to you.

Creating a Clojure project with it creates a bunch of folders: Source Packages, which contains a default package called com.yourcompany, Test Packages, Libraries, which contains the .jar for Clojure and a link to the JDK, and Test Libraries, which contains JUnit.

Comment: Is JUnit recommended for Clojure testing?  I'd expect there to be something more Clojure-ish.

Comment: You can find more about unit testing in Clojure here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Tutorials_and_Tips#Unit_Testing_in_Clojure

Answer (score 1):

I use a combo of:

- Intellij Idea with the La Clojure plugin
- [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen)
- [Clojars](http://clojars.org/)
- [Midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje), for testing/mocking
- Git

Good luck!